# Convert String to UTF-16 Byte Array in GJS

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

In my Gnome Extension I would like to call `GLib.convert`. Sadly it does not work with strings but wants a ByteArray. Now I wonder how to convert a Javascript String into a UTF-16 Byte Array.

Bonus points if this uses some part of the Gnome bindings instead of implementing in Javascript.

Comment: Or is it the undocumented and deprecated `ByteArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ByteArray.fromString(someString, 'UTF-16')` will convert your JS string into a UTF-16-encoded `Uint8Array`. This can be passed to `GLib.convert` (although, since fromString should understand all the encodings that `GLib.convert` does, maybe you don't need to after that?)

See also the [ByteArray documentation](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/blob/master/doc/ByteArray.md).